# Cannot boot in Ubuntu after restoring Ubuntu using timeshift

Tags: boot, grub2, backup, dconf, timeshift

recently I was using Ubuntu and I tried to delete a service called dconf-service which ended up breaking up my system
But I had used a app callled time shift which is a backup application for Linux

But when I reinstalled Ubuntu and started the backup process everything was fine but when I unplugged my external HDD(which I had the backup files that time shift created)everything was black, when I tried to boot up it doesn’t boot into Ubuntu it shows an error that it can’t boot

So I decided to reinstall my system again from another usb but it also doesn’t work

This is the error that I get when booting into a USB:

GNU grub version 2.04
Minimal bash like line editing is supported

I don’t know why this happens
If someone has any idea how to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: Which scenario are you trying to troubleshoot? Are you trying to restore a timeshift backup or are you troubleshooting being unable to reinstall Ubuntu?  Are you sure that your installation media is valid? Does it pass integrity checks? Can you boot into a live session (Try Ubuntu)?

Comment: i was trying to backup my system using timeshift, i remember creating a snapshot in my external HDD, but when i installed ubuntu again and done the backup process everything was fine until i unplugged my external HDD when i done that the screen had gone black, 
when i realised this i tried to reinstall my system again using a usb drive flashed with a program called balena etcher, when i tried to boot up using the f12 key and selecting the uefi OS option this error comes up:

GNU GRUB version 2.04
Minimal bash like line editing for the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.